# window.print() not working in stock browser; Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Tags: javascript, android, browser, printing, samsung-mobile

I am creating one web application. It has one print link on it which calls

```
window.print();
```

function of javascript. It works fine in Chrome and Safari. But its not working in the Samsung Stock browsers in android. Please suggest how to initiate print in these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [***window.print()***](http://wiki.nsbasic.com/Window.print%28%29) documentation, the command is not supported on Android devices.  You can use the [***Google Cloud Print Web Element***](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget) to add print functionality.  You will need to implement a browser sniffer to determine which device is being used.

An online search will most likely provide you with options utilizing [***NavigatorID.userAgent***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) property, however, this has been deprecated and may not work in the near future. [***Feature testing***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) is probably your best option.

Hopefully this will help you get pointed in the right direction.